# material-ui causing vscode IntelliSense to slow down

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Just adding the core `@material-ui/core` package into a blank react project causes IntelliSense to go from near instant to 2-5 seconds, is there anything that can improve performance here?

Comment: That is very annoying, it also happens for me.
I am not working with MUI because of that..